# grunt-couch failing with error in task.js:205:15 & taskjs.:241:33

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, couchapp

I'm not sure where this error is coming from - a misconfigured grunt.initConfig object, my files, or grunt itself. The error output is not clear about what might be wrong...

The error output:

```
Error: Task "couch-compile:app" failed.
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Dev/gitlab/theapp/src/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:205:15)
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/me/Dev/gitlab/theapp/src/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:241:33)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

I tried figuring it out from other projects getting the same error in the task.js file, but I don't understand what's going on.

My couchapp works with the python version of `couchapp push`, so getting my project into a format usable by this grunt plugin could be my problem. My structure is basically (almost exactly) what is being expected by this plugin though. I've had to exclude some files that the `.couchappignore` file lists (the grunt-couch plugin doesn't account for that).

My `grunt.initConfig` object:

```
'couch-compile': {
    app: {
        files: {
            'app.json' ['!*.txt','!*.sh','!_docs','!.couchapp*','webapp/**/*']
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me whether it's my file structure, my grunt config object, or if the grunt-couch plugin is the one throwing the error?

Thanks.

Comment: I realize I didn't add very much info about my project structure, so let me know what would be useful to know.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I gave up and moved on to other things.